Metric on an embedded product of two hyperbolic planes
The product of two copies of $H^2:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid \operatorname{Im}(z)>0\}$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{P}^3$ via the Segre embedding
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\sigma: & \mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1 &\to& \mathbb{P}^3 \\
        &  [(z:t),(z':t')]&\mapsto & (zz':zt':z't:tt')
\end{array}
$$
(here we think of $H^2$ as a subset of the chart $\{(z:1)\}\subset\mathbb{P}^1$).
The image of $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ under $\sigma$ is a quadric $Q:=\{u_{00}u_{11}-u_{01}u_{10}=0\}$.
$H^2$ has the natural metric with geodesics being semicircles with centers on the real axis $\{y=0\}$ (in the closure). Is it possible to set up a metric on
$\sigma(H^2\times H^2)$ so that its restrictions to the lines of $Q$ induce the original $H^2$ metric (in a fixed affine chart of $\mathbb{P}^3$)?
I suspect it could be done by choosing a family of quadratic functions $P_{\nu} P_{\overline{\nu}}$, where
$P_\nu(u):=\sum_{j\leq k\leq 1}\nu_{jk}u_{jk}$, $\nu_{jk}\in\mathbb{C}$,
so that in the affine chart $\{u_{11}=1\}$ the geodesics of the metric lie
on $P_{\nu} P_{\overline{\nu}}=r^2$, but I have trouble pinning this down.

Well, this seems to be clearly possible on $H^2 \times H^2$ itself: you can take any $L^p$ combination of the metrics of the factors. (If you only care about Riemannian metrics, then this forces $p = 2$ and the choice is actually more or less unique.)
Now $\sigma$ is a homeomorphism onto its image (with respect to the transcendental topology) --- this is precisely what "embedding" means. So, if I am not mistaken, nothing prevents from pushing whatever metric you chose on $H^2 \times H^2$ forward by $\sigma$; and then the image metric will of course still have the same properties.
It should even be possible to explicitly compute a formula for this image metric. I do not really have the time to do so right now, but (if no-one does it before me) will certainly try to do it once the holidays are over.
